# Hiding certain columns on an Excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-hiding, excel-tables

I've been trying to hide table columns on my Excel spreadsheet. While I can hide entire columns if my data was not in table form, this is something I cannot do because of the information that is underneath the table. For the purposes of this spreadsheet, that information needs to be below. So I can't really convert the table and I can't hide the information that is irrelevant.

Does anyone have a solution for this (this seems like a basic problem but I'm relatively new to Excel)?

Comment: Nope, You can only hide full columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention if that table above moves in number of rows or not but another option is to Data ---> GROUP the rows of the table and then collapse them. Select ALL rows relevant to the table and then click GROUP. To left of row numbers you'll have a line to click (with a + or -) to expand or collapse the data. This will visually look like only the data below is present and you can set print ranges to only look at the data below.

Hope that helps

Comment: Still encountered the same problem but has made it look much better visually for sure. Thanks so much!

Comment: If this solved your problem kindly accept it as answer by clicking tick mark at top left of answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only hide full columns. If hiding the data in the table is important, then the data below needs to be moved to a different sheet. Or, if it only needs to be hidden when printed, then you can change the font color to match the background color.